# docker-compose doesn't clean cache or temporary files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

Using docker-compose, after joining a cluster of Rabbitmq using:

```bsh
docker-compose up
docker exec -it rabbitmq3 bash
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbitmq2
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Every time I restart docker-compose the cluster is on.
Even after removing the containers and pruning the system:

```bsh
docker-compose down
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}")
docker volume prune
docker system prune
```

How can I reset the containers?

```yaml
version: "3.2"
services:
  rabbitmq2:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11-rc-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbitmq2
    container_name: 'rabbitmq2'
    ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
    - "5552:5552"
    - "15692:15692"
    volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: $PWD/advanced/rabbitmq2/advanced.config
       target: /etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
     - type: bind
       source: $PWD/history/rabbitmq2/.bash_history
       target: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.bash_history
     - type: bind
       source: $PWD/cookie/rabbitmq2/.erlang.cookie
       target: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
    networks:
    - rabbitmq_net
    environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit_admin
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=.123-321.
    - RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILES=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    - RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
    - RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@rabbitmq2
  rabbitmq3:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11-rc-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbitmq3
    container_name: 'rabbitmq3'
    depends_on:
    - rabbitmq2
    links:
    - rabbitmq2
    ports:
    - "5673:5672"
    - "15673:15672"
    - "5553:5552"
    - "15693:15692"
    volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: $PWD/advanced/rabbitmq3/advanced.config
       target: /etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
     - type: bind
       source: $PWD/history/rabbitmq3/.bash_history
       target: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.bash_history
     - type: bind
       source: $PWD/cookie/rabbitmq3/.erlang.cookie
       target: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
     - type: bind
       source: $PWD/conf/rabbitmq3/rabbitmq.conf
       target: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    networks:
    - rabbitmq_net
    environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit_admin
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=.123-321.
    - RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILES=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    - RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config
    - RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@rabbitmq3
networks:
  rabbitmq_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: this `docker rm $(docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}")` will not remove running containers. You need to add `-f`.  The prune operation only removes unused resources. So if there is anything using those resources (like a running container) they will still be there. Also I don't see a `docker-compose down` in your list of commands.

Comment: @Mihai, now I used `docker-compose down`, and listed all containers `docker ps`, all containers stopped, then I executed `docker system prune`, but the problem persists

Comment: so if you  run `docker container ls -a` you don't see any entry anymore? Then can you explain better the problem, because I don't get it. Processes die with the container.

Comment: rabbitmq starts standalone, but I can join a broker to another broker making a cluster. I don't know exactly what happens when I join a broker, I know that a file is created `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq3/cluster_nodes.config` containing all brokers, but everytime that I restart the containers, the cluster is configured, I can't start from zero again.

Comment: You use local folders for volumes, like `$PWD/advanced/rabbitmq3/advanced.config`. Those are not cleaned up by docker. You need to manually delete them if you want to start clean.

Comment: thanks very much, in `$PWD/conf/rabbitmq3/rabbitmq.conf` the cluster is configured automatically, It is needed to remove the configuration and clean the volumes `docker volume prune $(docker volume ls -q)`

Answer (score 3):

You are using host folders, not docker volumes, for persistence.

This means that `docker volume prune` has no effect on your setup.

Each time you start the services they will map host folders to container folders. When you shutdown the containers the files will still exist on the host.

For a clean start you need to manually delete all the host folders that are mentioned in `docker-compose.yml`. No docker command will do that for you.